# Issue with frame.setSize on macOS (java code)

Tags: java, macos, swing, preferences

I use some classes to get my main frame preferences (locaion and size). Here the following code I use. It works well on Linux and Windows. Buton macOs I have a strange error.
Indeed, if I resize the windows to fit the screen (manually, not with the maximize button) and I close the app. The app will reopen with a tiny size at the left bottom of my screen. It only occurs when I quit with the frame having a full size.

It is like if frame.setSize(dim) does not work when dim has dimension greater than the screen.

However, I also tried to write this code in WindoHandler with no sucess:

```
Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(WindowHandler.class.getSimpleName() + "-" + frameUniqueId);
Dimension savedDim = getFrameSize(prefs, defaultW, defaultH);
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
// The following test is needed on macOS.
if ((savedDim.getWidth() >= screenSize.getWidth()) || (savedDim.getHeight() >= screenSize.getHeight())) {
    frame.setSize(screenSize);
    frame.setLocation(new Point(0, 0));
} else {
    frame.setSize(savedDim);
    frame.setLocation(getFrameLocation(prefs, defaultX, defaultY));
}
```

EDIT:
I also tried:

```
    frame.setPreferredSize(getFrameSize(prefs, defaultW, defaultH));
    frame.setLocation(getFrameLocation(prefs, defaultX, defaultY));
    frame.pack();
```

with no sucess too....

My classes:

```
package org.spview.preferences;                                                                                                                                           

import java.awt.Dimension;                                                                                                                                                
import java.awt.Point;                                                                                                                                                    
import java.awt.Toolkit;                                                                                                                                                  
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;                                                                                                                                   
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;                                                                                                                                     
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;                                                                                                                                       

import javax.swing.JFrame;                                                                                                                                                
import javax.swing.UIManager;                                                                                                                                             
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;                                                                                                                       

import org.spview.Main;                                                                                                                                                   

//import com.apple.eawt.FullScreenUtilities;                                                                                                                              

public class WindowHandler {                                                                                                                                              
    public static void registerFrame(JFrame frame, String frameUniqueId, int defaultX, int defaultY, int defaultW,                                                        
            int defaultH) {                                                                                                                                               

        Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(WindowHandler.class.getSimpleName() + "-" + frameUniqueId);                                                       
        frame.setSize(getFrameSize(prefs, defaultW, defaultH));                                                                                                           
        frame.setLocation(getFrameLocation(prefs, defaultX, defaultY));                                                                                                   

        CoalescedEventUpdater updater = new CoalescedEventUpdater(400, () -> updatePref(frame, prefs));                                                                   

        frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {                                                                                                               
            @Override                                                                                                                                                     
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {                                                                                                              
                updater.update();                                                                                                                                         
            }                                                                                                                                                             

            @Override                                                                                                                                                     
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {                                                                                                                
                updater.update();                                                                                                                                         
            }                                                                                                                                                             
        });                                                                                                                                                               
    }                                                                                                                                                                     

    private static void updatePref(JFrame frame, Preferences prefs) {                                                                                                     
        Point location = frame.getLocation();                                                                                                                             
        prefs.putInt("x", location.x);                                                                                                                                    
        prefs.putInt("y", location.y);                                                                                                                                    
        Dimension size = frame.getSize();                                                                                                                                 
        prefs.putInt("w", size.width);                                                                                                                                    
        prefs.putInt("h", size.height);                                                                                                                                   
    }                                                                                                                                                                     

    private static Dimension getFrameSize(Preferences pref, int defaultW, int defaultH) {                                                                                 
        int w = pref.getInt("w", defaultW);                                                                                                                               
        int h = pref.getInt("h", defaultH);                                                                                                                               
        return new Dimension(w, h);                                                                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                                                                     

    private static Point getFrameLocation(Preferences pref, int defaultX, int defaultY) {                                                                                 
        int x = pref.getInt("x", defaultX);                                                                                                                               
        int y = pref.getInt("y", defaultY);                                                                                                                               
        return new Point(x, y);                                                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                                                     
}
```

---

```
package org.spview.preferences;                                                                                                                                           

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;                                                                                                                                        
import javax.swing.Timer;                                                                                                                                                 

public class CoalescedEventUpdater {                                                                                                                                      
    private Timer timer;                                                                                                                                                  

    public CoalescedEventUpdater(int delay, Runnable callback) {                                                                                                          
        timer = new Timer(delay, e -> {                                                                                                                                   
            timer.stop();                                                                                                                                                 
            callback.run();                                                                                                                                               
        });                                                                                                                                                               
    }                                                                                                                                                                     

    public void update() {                                                                                                                                                
        if (!SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {                                                                                                                    
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {                                                                                                                            
                timer.restart();                                                                                                                                          
            });                                                                                                                                                           
        } else {                                                                                                                                                          
            timer.restart();                                                                                                                                              
        }                                                                                                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                                                                                     
}
```

---

```
package org.spview;                                                                                                                                                       

import org.spview.preferences.WindowHandler;                                                                                                                              

import org.spview.gui.JobPlay;                                                                                                                                            

import java.util.Locale;                                                                                                                                                  


/**                                                                                                                                                                       
 * This is the entry point to SPVIEW application.                                                                                                                         
 */                                                                                                                                                                       
public class Main {                                                                                                                                                       

    public final static String PACKAGE_NAME = "SPVIEW";                                                                                                                   
    public final static String VERSION = "1.99";                                                                                                                          

    /**                                                                                                                                                                   
     * Start SPVIEW application.                                                                                                                                          
     */                                                                                                                                                                   
    public static void main(String[] args) {                                                                                                                              
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {                                                                                                           
            public void run() {                                                                                                                                           
                Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH); // messages in english                                                                                                 
                WindowHandler.setLookAndFeel();                                                                                                                           
                JobPlay jp = new JobPlay(); // instantiate the JobPlay main window                                                                                        
                WindowHandler.registerFrame(jp, Main.class.getName(), 0, 0, 1024, 768);                                                                                   
                jp.setVisible(true); // show it                                                                                                                           
            }                                                                                                                                                             
        });                                                                                                                                                               
    }                                                                                                                                                                     
}
```

Comment: *It is like if frame.setSize(dim) does not work when dim has dimension greater than the screen.* -- then add an edit to make sure it is not greater than the dimension of the screen.

Comment: As I wrote, I tried with no sucess